# ¿Como filtrar un select en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Quisiera filtrar la la información que estoy trayendo de una base de datos... para hacer un select

Me esta quedando de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No quiero valores repetidos...

con este codigo hago mi select:

```
<div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-4" >
<label class="control-label col-md-4" >Cartera: </label>
<div class="col-md-8">
 <select name="carteras_id" id="carteras_id" class="form-control">
@foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
  <option value="{{ $cartera->carteras_id }}" class="form-control">{{ $cartera->cartera }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Entonces es mejor hacer eso en la consulta a la base de datos, crea un query que no te traiga valores repetidos

Comment: no puedo... estoy trabajando con data... y tengo ya mucha informacion en esas tablas .. se supone que tendria que editar .. pero necesito algun tipo de funcion o algo para evitar que se repita la data solo en el select

Comment: prueba con los métodos de las colecciones, unique por ejemplo https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-unique

Answer (score 0):

Se que es tarde la posible respuesta pero a mi me funciona algo así por ejemplo. aunque como dices no puedes hacer la consulta espero le sirva a alguien más.

```
    $variable = DB::select("SELECT dato1, dato2, ..  FROM tabla GROUP BY dato1, ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY dato1");
```